# Asymptotic distribution of the MLE of an exponential via the CLT

Tags: probability, statistics, self-learning

Let $X_1,..,X_n$ i.i.d from an exponential distribution :
\begin{align*}
    f(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x} , x > 0
\end{align*}
I've computed the MLE and the Fisher information number :
\begin{align*}
\lambda_{MLE} &= \frac{1}{\bar{X}} \\
I(\lambda) &= \frac{1}{\lambda^2}
\end{align*}
I therefore obtain the following asymptotic distribution for $\lambda_{MLE} $ :
\begin{align}
    \sqrt{n} (\lambda_{MLE} - \lambda_0) \xrightarrow{D} \mathcal{N}(0,\lambda^2) 
\end{align}
I wish to check that my result is correct by using the CLT theorem and the Delta Method.
CLT :
\begin{align}
    \sqrt{n} (\bar{X}-\mu) \xrightarrow{D} \mathcal{N}(0,1/\lambda^2)
\end{align}
Because $\lambda^2$ is the variance of an exponential random variable.

The delta method states that :
\begin{align}
    \sqrt{n}(g(\hat{\theta}) -g(\theta)) \xrightarrow{D} \mathcal{N}(0,(g'(\theta))^2 \sigma^2(\theta) ) 
\end{align}
With in this case :
\begin{align}
    g(x) &= \frac{1}{x} \\
    \frac{dg(x)}{dx} &= \frac{-1}{x^2}
\end{align}
Therefore :
\begin{align}
\sqrt{n}(\lambda_{MLE} - \lambda_0) \xrightarrow{D} \mathcal{N}(0,\Big[\frac{-1}{\lambda^2}\Big]^2 \frac{1}{\lambda^2})
\end{align}
Which would yields an asymptotic variance of $1/\lambda^6$ which cannot be true.
What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use delta method, you should use $\theta = \frac{1}{\lambda}$ but not $\theta = \lambda$. In this case

\begin{align}
\sqrt{n}(\lambda_{MLE} - \lambda_0) \xrightarrow{D} \mathcal{N}(0,\Big[\frac{-1}{\theta^2}\Big]^2 \frac{1}{\lambda^2})
\end{align}

Comment: It makes sense, thank you